# Managing SQL Server's memory

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

While loading a table with ~17M rows (around 2GB in size) to a SQLServer using the BulkCopy class, the server seems to silently run out of memory after loading about 6M records. i.e., I takes up a bit more than 90% of the system's memory and after that without raising an out of memory exception silently continues to try loading data which is becomes extremely slow.

Has anyone else run into similar issues? Is there any way to tell SQLServer to clear up some memory without restarting it? If no, can anyone tell me how to restart the server programatically?

PS: I have confirmed that it isn't my program that is eating up the memory.

[EDIT] I am running a 64 bit Windows 7, 64 bit sqlserver 2008 R2, with 8gigs of memory.

Comment: How have you been able to confirm that your program is not the cause of the memory consumption?

Comment: oh, when I kill my process much lesser memory is freed than when I restart the sql server

Comment: Have set BatchSize to you object? Else it would fill the transaction log file.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server will allocate all the memory available on the system. Once it reaches the maximum memory, it will stay there and not free that memory. This is the by design intended behavior.

You did not tell us some critical pieces of information:

- how much physical memory does the system has?
- is a 64bit or a 32bit OS?
- is a 64bit or a 32bit SQL Server instance?

My suspicion is that your seeing actually something completely unrelated: at 6M rows your test starts growing files and you do not have [instant file initialization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175935.aspx) turned on. There are plenty of performance counters to look at:

- [Database object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189883.aspx)
- [Buffer Manager object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189628.aspx)
- [Wait Statistics](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190732.aspx)

And, as with any SQL Server troubleshooting problem, following the [Waits and Queues](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966413.aspx) methodology cannot hurt. Finally, if is indeed  memory pressure caused problem, there are guidelines how to investigate at [Using DBCC MEMORYSTATUS to Monitor SQL Server Memory Usage](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/271624).

Comment: thanks! I have added the specs. Regarding file initialization - I am pre-allocating ~10gig disk space, I don't mind wallclock time as long as all the data is loaded and indexes are created. what do I do with the counters? Its for monitoring right?
Basically, my case is that I know a lot more rows are going to be added and my workaround for it has been to restart the sqlserver to regain memory, and it happily loads more until it uses up all the memory. I will try `DBCC MEMORYSTATUS` and read up on waits and queues, if you think of anything in the meanwhile, that'd be awesome.

Comment: I would suggest you check the `wait_time`, `wait_type`, `wait_resource` and `last_wait_type` values in `sys.dm_exec_requests` for the session doing the BCP. check repeatedly, while is being fast and when has slowed down, post here the values you see most often.

Answer (score 1):

Sql has some overhead for loading all that data into memory so while you may have 2gb of raw data there is metadata and pointers and such that must be loaded into memory to keep track of those things. What's happening on your system is that you are running out of RAM storage to keep everything in memory and therefore certain pages (unit that the OS uses to translate virtual addresses to physical ones) must be swapped to the hard drive (very slow) so that room can be made to store more information. Usually loading the database completely into memory will do this as databases can get quite large. Sql server has custom memory management so that it will usually get rid of things that have not been used recently and are not likely to be used in the near future.

Restarting Sql when this happens is really the only easy way to do this, depending on your particualr version of Sql (MySql, MsSql, etc...) there are ways to restart the server programatically.